# Is the return value of an assignment to an undefined property of HTMLElement#style guaranteed to be the same as the assigned value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is the return value of an assignment to an undefined property of HTMLElement#style guaranteed to be the same as the assigned value?

More generally, is assignment to (declared or undeclared) properties of host objects always guaranteed to return the same value assigned? And, if not, are style properties safe?

In other words, is this safe?

```
var node = document.getElementById("#foo");
node.style.WebkitTransition = 
    node.style.MozTransition = 
    node.style.OTransition = '0.4s all linear';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your example is safe.  According to the [ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf#page=97), an assignment expression always returns the value of the right-hand side of the expression.  Your example would be evaluated as:

```
// original
node.style.WebkitTransition = 
    node.style.MozTransition = 
    node.style.OTransition = '0.4s all linear';
// step 1
node.style.WebkitTransition = 
    node.style.MozTransition = 
    ('0.4s all linear');
// step 2
node.style.WebkitTransition = 
    ('0.4s all linear');
```

Since this is part of the language specification, I wouldn't expect it to matter what type of object or variable the left-hand side of the assignment is.

Comment: This sounds right to me. In section 11.13.1 (Simple Assignment), the last step is `Return rval.` So as long as no exceptions are thrown before that step, it seems the result is guaranteed to be identical to the value on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the method described above is safe. You are basically just chaining var assignments. It would be the same as saying

```
var c = 'value';
var b = c;
var a = b;

console.log(a) => 'value'
```

Comment: but it's not necessarily the same, because these are properties of host objects. Or is it?

Comment: The end result is the same because the value assigned will override all exisiting/undefined properties in the chain.

Comment: isn't it possible that a host object could use a value other than what you tried to assign? In that case would that part of the expression result in  the value the host object chose, or the value you tried to assign?

Comment: well for example if I do `var foo = document.body.children = {bar:2}`, foo is set to my object literal, but `document.body.children` is not. I just wonder if it always works like this by definition... even though the attempted assigned value wasn't actually assigned, that part of the expression still resulted in that value.

Comment: I guess it depends on the property. In your example above the style property will be overridden properly but a property like document.forms will always return a collection of forms from the DOM even if you try to reassign it's value.

Comment: "More generally, is assignment to (declared or undeclared) properties of host objects always guaranteed to return the same value assigned?" This should be true when dealing with properties such as attributes, but not for properties that return collections like you stated document.body.children

Comment: but it actually *does* result in the value i tried to assign in those cases, it just doesn't actually *assign* the value